# How to process tracked information in Application Insights

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am using Application Insights to track events in my web pages:

```
appInsights.trackEvent("my-event", { test: true });
```

However I can see that each entry in the log, collects some info regarding several other things like:

- User Id
- Session Id
- **Operation name**

The last one is sensitive as I can get the name of the computer or some other stuff. In order to comply to the GDPR, I wanna strip out those info from my log.

How do I tell Application Insights, to process the data before logging them? In my case, I would like to get access to the object which will be sent out by `trackEvent` and modify it before it is transmitted.

Comment: @PeterBons: You should add it an an answer, it is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TelemetryInitializers](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#addtelemetryinitializer) for that. They allow you to modify items *before* they are send to Application Insights

In your case it could be as simple as

```
appInsights.queue.push(function () {
    appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function (envelope) {
        envelope.tags['ai.operation.name'] = 'xxx';
});
```